# Bolding a icon from React Native using lib: react-native-vector-icons

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons

How can i get a bold icon from `react-native-vector-icon` or pass style props to  component?

I tried to change font-weight css from browser dev tool and it's worked

Answer (score 0):

You can't bold a vector icon only increase size on vector icon using fontSize style props.